# Can you run python scripts in chrome extensions?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension

I was using python to send requests to an API and process it but can the script be integrated in a chrome extension?

Comment: https://pythonspot.com/create-a-chrome-plugin-with-python/

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you want to run python code from browser, try using jupyter-notebook https://jupyter.org/ or python shell Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python-shell/gdiimmpmdoofmahingpgabiikimjgcia?hl=en). If you can achieve your goal with above options, it might be easier to use.

On the otherhand, if you want complete control over browser and with python code, please try tools like Selenium (https://www.selenium.dev/) and run those tools with Chrome.